# Simplify Pattern Matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I'm trying to implement a pattern matching using JavaScript and would like to ask for suggestions. The pattern is calculated based on the existence of the object arguments. I think the current pseudocode is too verbose. Is there any way I can simplify it? (Please ignore Param1 and Param2)

[image]

pseudocode:

```js
Pattern1: if null(3,4,5,6)      
Pattern2: if notNull(3,4,5,6)       
Pattern3: if notNull(6) and null(3,4,5)     
Pattern4: if notNull(5) and null(3,4,6)     
Pattern5: if notNull(4) and null(3,5,6)     
Pattern6: if notNull(3) and null(4,5,6)     
Pattern7: if notNull(5,6) and null(3,4)     
Pattern8: if notNull(4,6) and null(3,5)     
Pattern9: if notNull(3,6) and null(4,5)     
Pattern10: if notNull(4,5) and null(3,4)        
Pattern11: if notNull(3,5) and null(4,6)        
Pattern12: if notNull(3,4) and null(5,6)        
Pattern13: if notNull(3,4,5) and null(6)        
Pattern14: if notNull(3,4,6) and null(5)        
Pattern15: if notNull(3,5,6) and null(4)        
Pattern16: if notNull(4,5,6) and null(3)
```

Comment: This is not code...  It looks like the logic behind the code.  Where are the values stored - array?  object?  html?  `null` and `notNull` are not functions in javascript (afaik), and if you want to write these functions, I suggest you don't use a reserved word(?) "null".

Comment: @iAmOren, yes, you're right. I corrected my statement, this is the logic behind the code. The param1-6 are stored in an object.

Comment: Good...  details about the object, please.  an example would be nice.  `obj=={"1":"x","2":"o"...}`?

Comment: You could just hash your data and match this hash with your patterns. It can something as simple as just a string like "010011" where 0 is null and 1 is not null. And then you can just compare it against associative array where hash is key and value is function that needs to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; if

```
function check(params, ...list) {
  for (let i = 2; i < params.length; ++i) {
    if (params[i] == null) {
      if (list.includes(i)) return false;
    } else if (!list.includes(i)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

were defined, then you could write patterns thus:

```
Pattern3: if check(arguments, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored it by using the following pseudocode.

```js
patterns = [
    [false,false,false,false],
    [true,true,true,true],
    [false,false,false,true],
    [false,false,true,false],
    [false,true,false,false],
    [true,false,false,false],
    [false,false,true,true],
    [false,true,false,true],
    [true,false,false,true],
    [false,true,true,false],
    [true,false,true,false],
    [true,true,false,false],
    [true,true,true,false],
    [true,true,false,true],
    [true,false,true,true],
    [false,true,true,true],
]

patterns.findIndex(pattern => /* do params match? */)
```